# Is it safe to allocate memory within `unsafeDupablePerformIO`?

Tags: haskell, memory, memory-leaks, unsafe-perform-io

Suppose that I have a foreign function:

```
-- | Turns char* of the given size into a char* of size 16.
doSomethingFfi :: Ptr CUChar -> Ptr CUChar -> CSize -> IO ()
doSomethingFfi = undefined
```

The function is pure, so I would like to represent it as a pure function in Haskell:

```hs
doSomething :: ByteArray bytes => bytes -> bytes
doSomething bs = unsafePerformIO $
  alloc 16 $ \outPtr ->
  withByteArray bs $ \inPtr ->
    doSomethingFfi outPtr inPtr (fromIntegral $ length bs)
```

(Here I am using [`alloc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.15.0/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#v:alloc) from `memory`.)

My understanding is that the only difference between `unsafePerformIO` and `unsafeDupablePerformIO` is that the IO action in the latter can be silently terminated without any cleanup.

In my case above there are, essentially, two IO actions happening: 1. memory allocation; 2. foreign call. I am not concerned about 2, since it is pure, however I am worried about the memory.

Is there any guarantee that the memory allocated this way will not leak if the computation is interrupted silently? If the foreign function also required temporary storage that I had to allocate / clean up and I used [`alloca`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:alloca) for this purpose, would it still be safe to use `unsafeDupablePerformIO`?

Comment: That sounds pretty leaky to me! Are you not getting good enough performance from `unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: `alloca`, however, should be safe in this context, I believe. It allocates pinned memory in the garbage-collected heap, so if your `IO` is aborted, it should be cleaned up.

Comment: @dfeuer I haven’t benchmarked it, so let’s say the question is purely academic :). I was just wondering which function I should use in this case and noticed that, e.g. `cryptonite` [uses `unsafeDupablePerformIO`](https://github.com/haskell-crypto/cryptonite/blob/4622e5fc8ece82f4cf31358e31cd02cf020e558e/Crypto/Internal/Compat.hs#L22-L32) and started wondering if this is a good idea.

Comment: I think `alloc` allocates pinned garbage-collected memory too. My question can be reformulated as “does GHC guaratnee that the GC will collect the memory that resulted from an allocation within a silently aborted IO”?

Comment: It *looks* to me like `alloc` uses `malloc`ed memory. It attaches a finalizer to free it, but I don't think you get any guarantee that the finalizer will be installed before your computation is aborted.

Comment: In particular, adding a finalizer inherently requires allocation of a `Weak#` object, which allocation could cause the GC to run and the computation to be aborted as redundant. (In this case, more than just a `Weak#` is allocated, but there's really no way around that part at all.)

Comment: Hmmm .... Actually, `alloc` can use different allocation strategies for different class instances. Some seem to `malloc`; I'm not sure about others.

Comment: Ah, it's important to note that `alloc` is a class method. I was looking at the [implementation for `Bytes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.15.0/docs/src/Data.ByteArray.Bytes.html#bytesAllocRet) and you are probably looking at something else. So it also depends on the instance...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question to reflect the fact that I am interested in the generic case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly as I explained in the comments, but not quite:

#### `alloca`

As `alloca` is currently implemented, this is safe. `alloca` is implemented by a call to `allocaBytesAligned`, which is defined thus:

```
allocaBytesAligned :: Int -> Int -> (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b
allocaBytesAligned (I# size) (I# align) action = IO $ \ s0 ->
     case newAlignedPinnedByteArray# size align s0 of { (# s1, mbarr# #) ->
     case unsafeFreezeByteArray# mbarr# s1 of { (# s2, barr#  #) ->
     let addr = Ptr (byteArrayContents# barr#) in
     case action addr     of { IO action' ->
     case action' s2      of { (# s3, r #) ->
     case touch# barr# s3 of { s4 ->
     (# s4, r #)
  }}}}}
```

This allocates pinned memory in the garbage-collected heap. If your action is aborted early, then the garbage collector will reclaim the memory it allocated sooner or later.

#### `alloc`

This is not *necessarily* safe, but may actually be safe in practice. `alloc` is defined using a class method, `allocRet`, which different types can implement differently.

Contrary to my guesses in the comments, the instances defined in `memory` all *seem* fine—they too allocate pinned memory. But the class does not document this as a requirement, and in principle someone could allocate memory using `Foreign.Marshall.Alloc.malloc`, in which case the garbage collector will not take care of the memory automatically. Such a hypothetical implementation would have no way to ensure memory is freed if the computation aborts early.

Comment: Does GHC guarantee that `newAlignedPinnedByteArray#` is “atomic” in the sense that the thread is terminated either before `malloc` or after it is “properly registered” with the garbage collector?

Comment: @kirelagin, the primops don't call `malloc`. I'm not familiar with the mechanics of pinned memory, but as a rule, primops *can't* be interrupted except at the very moment they allocate. I wouldn't worry about it.